# How to switch two digits in an array with only one digit?

Tags: c

How to do this:

array 1: `2  8 5 7 3 5`
array 2: `2018 5 7 3 5`

The problem said that if two even numbers are consecutive in the first array, put a `2018` in their place, like so.
How can I do this?

```
for(a=n-1; a>=0; a--)
{
    if( b[a]%2==0 && b[a-1]%2==0)
    {
        for(c=a-1; c<n-1; c++)
        {
            b[c]=b[c+1];
        }
        b[a]= 2017;
    }

}
```

Comment: When `a` reaches `0` (i.e. `a == 0`) then what happens with `b[a - 1]`?

Comment: And how to do *what?* It's really unclear what you're asking about and what you want to do. For some specified input, what should the output be? What is the output your [mcve] creates? Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Well probably doesn't work, I have no idea how to do it

Comment: I want to switch 2 numbers from any array with only 1

Comment: Here, 2 and 8 from the first array are even and consecutive so we put an 2018 in that place

Comment: I don't know how to place *2018* in the place of 2 and 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really change the size of an array, but you can shift the elements and ignore elements at the end:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void shift_left(int* arr, size_t sz, size_t shift_cnt)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i != sz - shift_cnt; ++i)
  {
    arr[i] = arr[i + shift_cnt];
  }
  for (size_t i = sz - shift_cnt; i != sz; ++i)
  {
    arr[i] = 0;
  }
}

int main()
{
  int arr[] = { 2, 8, 5, 7, 3, 5 };
  size_t sz = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < sz - 1;)
  {
    if (arr[i] % 2 == 0 && arr[i + 1] % 2 == 0)
    {
      shift_left(arr + i, sz-- - i, 1);
      arr[i] = 2018;
    }
    else
    {
      ++i;
    }
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i != sz; ++i)
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);

  return 0;
}

// Output: 2018 5 7 3 5
```

Comment: @AndreiJarca Welcome! Also note that this will replace three consecutive even numbers with a single 2018, since 2018 itself is even and after replacing the first two, you still have 2018 and one other even next to each other. Hopefully this is the desired behavior. If it is not, fixing it should not be hard. I can help on that if needed

Answer (score 0):

March down the source array looking for even pairs

```
// return size used

size_t AJ_squish(int *dest, size_t dest_size, const int *src, size_t src_size) {
  size_t dest_len = 0;
  while (src_size > 1 && dest_len < dest_size) {
    // 2 evens in a row?
    if (src[0] % 2 == 0 && src[1] % 2 == 0) {
      dest[dest_len++] = 2018;
      src_size -= 2;
    } else {
      dest[dest_len++] = *src++;
      src_size--;
    }
  }
  if (src_size >  0 && dest_len < dest_size) {
    dest[dest_len++] = *src;
  }
  return dest_len;
}
```